# Overriding font-size for ?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall

Tags: android, android-theme

I have been using `?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall` and `?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium` very frequently in my application. I know that `?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall` defaults to `font-size` `14sp` and `?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium` defaults to `font-size` `18sp`.

Now, our testing team want the `font-size` for `?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall` to be `16sp`. Is there a way, we can override these values so that I don't have to visit screen by screen and line by line to replace them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone is dealing with similar issue, I just figured out the answer.

I added following line in my `AppTheme`

```
<item name="android:textAppearanceSmall">@style/AppTheme.TextAppearance.Small</item>
```

And then I created a new `style` like

```
<style name="AppTheme.TextAppearance.Small" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

Thank you

Comment: As a sidenote, I also had to set the parent differently for it to work. I used:

<style name="TextAppearance.Large" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large">

and referenced it from a custom theme:

<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
<item name="android:textAppearanceLarge">@style/TextAppearance.Large</item>