# Android studio - textStyle: bold does not work

Tags: android, android-layout

I have seen similar questions but [possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47465500/overriding-font-size-for-androidattr-textappearancesmall) (this was the last one that I tried) don't work. The problem is that I can not set the text as bold nor change its size, it always appears non-bold and of the same size.

I need to display `@+id/contactName` as bold.

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/contactName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:paddingEnd="4dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/contactListTextPrimary"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
            tools:text="Contact title" />

<style name="contactListTextPrimary" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

The code above does not make the text bold, it always stays as it was before. Below is the complete `styles.xml` file.

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
        <item name="android:listDivider">@drawable/list_divider</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_status_bar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="android:tint">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>







    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="PreferenceThemeOverlay">
        <item name="preferenceScreenStyle">@style/Preference.PreferenceScreen</item>
        <item name="preferenceFragmentStyle">@style/PreferenceFragment</item>
        <item name="preferenceCategoryStyle">@style/Preference.Category</item>
        <item name="preferenceStyle">@style/Preference</item>
        <item name="preferenceInformationStyle">@style/Preference.Information</item>
        <item name="checkBoxPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.CheckBoxPreference</item>
        <item name="switchPreferenceCompatStyle">@style/Preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat</item>
        <item name="dialogPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.DialogPreference</item>
        <item name="editTextPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.DialogPreference.EditTextPreference
        </item>
        <item name="preferenceFragmentListStyle">@style/PreferenceFragmentList</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    </style>

    <style name="LicensesTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>

    <style name="searchTextHighlight">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>

    <style name="contactListTextPrimary" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="textPrimarySmall" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="textPrimary" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="textPrimaryLarge" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large">
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="textSecondary" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorSecondary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="textSecondarySmall" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorSecondary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="sectionTitleStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
        <item name="android:fontFeatureSettings">smcp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/activity_padding</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/activity_padding</item>
    </style>

    <style name="textMetaBubble">
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorSecondary</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ProgressBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:minHeight">12dip</item>
        <item name="background">@color/colorChipBackground</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolbarSubtitleAppearance" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Subtitle">
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorSecondary</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ToolbarTitleAppearance" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorSecondary</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>

    </style>

    <style name="roundImageView" parent="">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
    </style>

    <style name="forwardToSheetDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/forwardToBottomSheet</item>
    </style>

    <style name="forwardToBottomSheet" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="backgroundTint">@null</item>
        <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/forwardToAppearanceBottomSheetDialog</item>
    </style>

    <style name="forwardToAppearanceBottomSheetDialog" parent="">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">16dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">16dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that the *contactListTextPrimary* style is

```
<style name="contactListTextPrimary" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

but in the full styles file you have just

```
<style name="contactListTextPrimary" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Make them match according to the longer version and you should see a **bold** font.

Comment: I tried it already  but it has no effect.